# image position using figure

Tags: floats, positioning

I have this document and I want that both images be located in same page
or at least that every image be located at the top of the page.

Is there anyway to put bigger? I tried to modify the scale but I got this error "overfull `\hbox` (x pt too wide) in paragraph".

[image: First Page][image: Second Page]

Here is the code:

```
\section{Generar Boletines de información}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.49]{Escenario-generar-boletin.png}
\caption{Escenario - Generar Boletín de información}
\label{Escenario - Generar Boletín de información}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Diagrama-comunicacion-generar-boletin.png}
\caption{Comunicación - Generar Boletín de información}
\label{Comunicación - Generar Boletín de información}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be white margins in the PNG file, if you get an overfull `\hbox` warning. Just open the file in an image editor (Gimp or whatever) and remove
the white margins there. The new version of the file can then be included by

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{...}
```

to use the full line width for the image. If the fonts are still to small, then the image could included in a landscape figure or the image redesigned to better fit the target document layout.

BTW, it is very risky to use arbitrary text as name for `\label`. Especially the non-ASCII letters can cause serious trouble.

Comment: What do you mean with arbitrary text?

Comment: @LenaVonEngel The argument of `\label` is limited. Alphanumeric characters are usually safe. Other characters might work or fail depending on the circumstances (packages, active characters, ...).

Comment: @LenaVonEngel A good practice for labels is to use this convention:`\label{object:name}` where you use a few-letters name for the object, such as: fig (figure), tab (table), sec (section), cha (chapter), eq (equation) followed with a meaningful word (for you) that identifies the object you label.